# Shell 'echo' error with ENV VAR been parsed from 'redis-cli INFO' output

Tags: bash, shell, redis, environment-variables

I try to monitor Redis health with Zabbix agent and want to parse output for `redis-cli INFO` command:

```
$ redis-cli INFO
# Server
redis_version:4.0.9
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:9435c3c2879311f3
...
```

with `shell` script and compose JSON file with subset of info values:

```
{
  "redis_version": "4.0.9",
  "used_memory": 100,
  "used_memory_rss": 200
}
```

But I have an error when I try to echo parsed values to console. This is my demo script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_ECHO="/tmp/test_out.txt"
FILE_REDIS="/tmp/test_redis.txt"

echo "redis_version:4.0.9" >${FILE_ECHO}
/usr/bin/redis-cli INFO >${FILE_REDIS}

ECHO_VERSION=$(grep "redis_version" "${FILE_ECHO}")
REDIS_VERSION=$(grep "redis_version" "${FILE_REDIS}")

echo "{\"node\": \"${ECHO_VERSION}\"}"
echo "{\"node\": \"${REDIS_VERSION}\"}"
```

I expect that output will be:

```
{"node": "redis_version:4.0.9"}
{"node": "redis_version:4.0.9"}
```

in both cases, but actually I have:

```
{"node": "redis_version:4.0.9"}
"}node": "redis_version:4.0.9
```

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffpvrg4u085jn5/test_redis.txt?dl=0) is my `test_redis.txt`.

Comment: Check whether test_redis.txt has a carriage return.

Comment: Yes, `\r` is the reason. This works: `REDIS_VERSION=$(grep "redis_version" "${FILE_REDIS}" | tr -d '\r')`. Thanks, @user1934428.